# Create Azure DataDisk with C#

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to create a DataDisk in Azure with C#. But nothing seems to work. However was able to do it with PowerShell.

I use Azure SDK.
Below is a piece of code that is suppose to create a disk and attach it.

```
var vm = azure.VirtualMachines.List().Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == vmName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

var disk = new DataDisk(
                vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count + 1,
                DiskCreateOptionTypes.Empty,
                vmName + "_disk");

disk.DiskSizeGB = 128;
disk.Validate();
vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Add(disk);
vm.StorageProfile.Validate();
vm.Update();
```

I don't have any errors. But nothing is created.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `Apply()` method after `vm.Update()`. Please use `vm.Update().Apply()` instead of `vm.Update()` in your code.

Here is my test code, and works fine:

```
#your other code.
DataDisk disk = new DataDisk(vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count + 1,
                DiskCreateOptionTypes.Empty,
                "ivandisk222");

disk.DiskSizeGB = 15;
disk.Validate();
vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Add(disk);
vm.StorageProfile.Validate();

vm.Update().Apply();
```

After the code completes, I can see the data disk is added to the vm:

[image]